# What Visual Studio Files do I need to give to WiX, and how can I get them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wix, visual-studio-express

I have Visual Studio Express 2012, and I'm looking to create an installation project for it, using WiX. I can't use the plugin because it's Express, so I'm using the candle and light approach.

I know how to make the wxs file I need, but my problem is that I'm not sure what files to include in the setup app (ex. the actual application file) and how to get Visual Studio to give me these files.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.
-tradeJmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your project in the Release configuration, which will create `.exe` and perhaps `.dll` files in `bin\Release`.

Comment: Thanks, where would I find this "Release configuration?

Comment: Never mind, I found it. But in addition to the exe, there is a .exe.manifest, a .exe.config, a .vhost.exe.config, a .vhost.exe, a .application file and a .pdb file. Whick of these are needed?

Comment: @user117019: You might need to `.config` and the `.manifest`; you don't need the `.vshost.*`.  Try VS's Publish option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another machine?  I happen to know that WiX works nicely with the free Visual Studio Integrated Shell.